# Group context on pages generated by views

Tags: views, organic-groups, 7

I have two group page

node/%/posts and node/%/activity.

Inside these pages, I have a mini panel which requires group context to display. For some reason, the pages generated by views are not recognized as group context though its a menu tab inside the group. Did anyone had the same issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been an issue on the Organics Groups [page](http://drupal.org/node/1781386). Please refer to comment #6 for the solution.

The other way to work around this is to Use page manager to create pages instead of using views. Page manager helps to maintain the context of the group across its pages.